# Error al entrar Admin Prestashop 1.7.6

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

Tengo una tienda en prestashop, la tienda esta en buen estadfo todo esta normal, pero a la hora de querer entrar al panel de administracion me sale un error de la BD(Ajunto Imagen).
Edite el archivo parameters.php con los datos de la BD y esta todo correcto pero el panel de administrador parece no conectar a la DB.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje de error es bastante claro: El usuario o contraseña son incorrectos, revisa los archivos de configuración para verificar los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi, el usuario y contraseña estaban correctos.
El problema fue que prestashop usaba las credenciales que estaban guardadas en las cookies del CMS.
Solucion: Eliminar las cookies de prestashop.

Comment: ¿En serio guarda credenciales de acceso a base de datos en cookies? ¡Qué miedo!

Comment: En cookies de prestashop(backend).